# Getting Spacy to properly work with Pyspark, but getting a Typeerror error in the UDF

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, spacy

I'm trying to properly set up Spacy to work with my Pyspark code. I'm simply trying to use Spacy's functionalities such as extracting the POS for the various texts, Lemma, and etc. the problem is that its failing.

I'm running on windows 10 with python 3.7.0 and pyspark V2.4.3. The technique i followed was to use a user defined function(UDF) similar to this [stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50880303/python-pickle-spacy-for-pyspark) by user chris. The idea is to loop through the body of text and to separate it into chunks and pass each chunk to the UDF function to run Spacy.

```
def spacy_preprocessing_udf(text, lowercase, remove_stop):
    print("inside spacy_preprocessing")
    def preprocess(text):
        lowercase = True
        remove_stop = True
        arry = ["testing"]
        #print("inside preprocess")
        #print(text)
        global nlp

        try:
            #print("inside try")
            stops = spacy.lang.en.stop_words.STOP_WORDS
            if lowercase:
                text = text.lower()
            text = nlp(text)
            #print("after doc")
            #print("before loop try")
            teststt = ""
            listofword_pos = list()
            for word in text:
                lemma = word.lemma_.strip()
                if lemma:
                    if not remove_stop or (remove_stop and lemma not in stops):
                        lemnlp = nlp(lemma)
                        lemmaPOS = "dum"
                        for leword in lemnlp:
                            lemmaPOS = leword.pos_.strip()
                        # tuplpair = (lemma, lemmaPOS)
                        testst = lemma + " : " + lemmaPOS
                        print(testst)
                        teststt = testst
                        listofword_pos.append(testst)
            return listofword_pos
        except:
            #print("inside except")
            nlp = spacy.load("en")
            stops = spacy.lang.en.stop_words.STOP_WORDS
            if lowercase:
                text = text.lower()
            text = nlp(text)

            listofword_pos = list()
            teststt = ""
            #print("before loop")
            for word in text:
                lemma = word.lemma_.strip()
                if lemma:
                    if not remove_stop or (remove_stop and lemma not in stops):
                        lemnlp = nlp(lemma)
                        lemmaPOS = "dum"
                        for leword in lemnlp:
                          lemmaPOS = leword.pos_.strip()
                        #tuplpair = (lemma, lemmaPOS)
                        testst = lemma + " : " + lemmaPOS
                        print(testst)
                        teststt = testst
                        listofword_pos.append(testst)
                        print(len(listofword_pos))
            return listofword_pos
    res_udf = F.udf(preprocess(text), ArrayType(StringType()))

    return res_udf
```

```
loop:
                spacy_result = spacy_preprocessing_udf(text_list[index], True, True)

                spacylist = spacylist.append(spacy_result)
```

The thing is that the code successfully gets inside the Spacy method and even initiates Spacy and calls all those various Spacy methods(POS,Lemma,etc). when debugging i see examples such as **"run : verb"** which is correct. The issue is that its not properly returning the final List. I get the following error

> TYpeError: Invalid function: not a function or callable (**call** is not defined): class 'list'

which originates when its time to return the list in the UDF. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.